# Setting system memory for a process in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit

I need to limit the system memory free -- available for a process to 8GB. So, do I need to set

```
ulimit -S -m 8388608
```

or do I need to set:

```
ulimit -S -v 8388608
```

I am a non root user therefore I can change only soft limit. How can I raise the memory limit to unlimited again. I tried

```
ulimit -S -v ulimited
```

but it gives me:

```
 bash: ulimit: ulimited: invalid number
```

Answer (score 0):

'invalid number' happens, if there is a wrong line-ending, e.g. CR LF instead of Unix LF